# Does SAP version 4.7 require MS Sql Server Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sap

We've recently discovered that we weren't actually licensed for Enterprise and are now either paying to upgrade or re-installing our SQL Servers.

We've got a very old version of SAP (4.7) Running against one of our Enterprise servers, and I would like to down grade it if possible. I can't find any evidence to support 4.7 requiring or not requiring Enterprise edition. The later versions of SAP do.

Does anyone know?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition 2005 (9.00.5057.00) (64-bit)

Comment: Trying to get a SAP stack exchange started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition shouldn't be required.  What you'll loose by going to the standard edition will be that you won't be able to do online index rebuilds, won't be able to use the lock pages in memory feature, you won't be able to use table partitioning, as well as a couple of other small things.

From a SQL Server perspective you shouldn't have a problem using the standard edition.  If SAP requires it or not from a support perspective is a different issue.

Comment: I agree with your statement of "Should", however I'm looking for evidence of some sort I can wave infront of my boss, because the clueless consultants are telling us that it is required and $40k in licensing is on the line.

Comment: You should be able to put in an OSS Note with SAP to get a definitive answer on this.  In my experience SAP Consultant shops will stay with the safe answer which is to not touch anything that works.

Comment: There is always the if it isn't broke don't fix it. Why the license cost for a server that already exists?

Comment: Microsoft is auditing all their customers because they had a bad quarter. We thought we had licenses for enterprise, but apparently we were only licensed for standard.